# How to get the return value of a clicked button using NSAlert

Tags: applescript-objc

I am using the following:

```
tell current application's NSAlert's alloc's init()
  its setMessageText:"Alert test"
  its setInformativeText:"This is a test"
  its setAlertStyle:2
  its setShowsSuppressionButton:true
  its addButtonWithTitle:"Cancel"
  its addButtonWithTitle:"Replace"
  its beginSheetModalForWindow:theWindow modalDelegate:me didEndSelector:(missing value) contextInfo:(missing value)
end tell
```

I would like to know how do I get the value of the clicked button including "Suppression Button".
thanks advance!

Comment: Is this is for an Xcode project?  On both my Sierra and Mojave systems, using a `didEndSelector` crashes the application when using anything other than the default button, so it looks like an earlier bug came back - using the block-based methods via Myriad Helpers categories works OK though.

Comment: Yes, it is for an xcode project, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `NSAlert+MyriadHelpers` category from [Myriad Helpers](https://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/apps/helpers.html), you can use the `showOverWithSuppress:calling:` method.  Using Xcode’s default AppleScript application project and adding the category .h and .m files to it, an example would be something like:

```
property suppressed : false

on applicationWillFinishLaunching:aNotification
    tell current application's NSUserDefaults's standardUserDefaults
        its registerDefaults:{SuppressAlert:suppressed}
        set my suppressed to its objectForKey:"SuppressAlert"
    end tell
    set state to ""
    if not suppressed then set state to "not "
    set response to (display dialog "Example alert is currently " & state & "suppressed." buttons {"Clear", "Set", "Continue"} default button 3)
    if button returned of response is "Set" then
        set my suppressed to true
    else if button returned of response is "Clear" then
        set my suppressed to false
    end if
    doAlert()
end applicationWillFinishLaunching:

on doAlert()
    log "performing doAlert() handler"
    if suppressed then return -- skip it
    tell current application's NSAlert's alloc's init()
        its setMessageText:"Alert test"
        its setInformativeText:"This is a test"
        its setAlertStyle:2
        its setShowsSuppressionButton:true
        its addButtonWithTitle:"Cancel"
        its addButtonWithTitle:"Replace"
        its showOverWithSuppress:theWindow calling:"alertDidEnd:"
    end tell
end doAlert

on alertDidEnd:response
    set buttonName to (first item of response) as text
    if buttonName = "Cancel" then display alert "Cancel button clicked!"
    set my suppressed to (second item of response) as boolean
end alertDidEnd:

on applicationShouldTerminate:sender
    tell current application's NSUserDefaults's standardUserDefaults
        its setObject:suppressed forKey:"SuppressAlert" — update
    end tell
    return current application's NSTerminateNow
end applicationShouldTerminate:
```

Comment: Yes, and if you use a property or global variable for the suppress result then that can be used later to determine if the alert is shown again.

Comment: If I want to opt for something like, if and else I should include them like this: ```if buttonCancel = "Cancel" then
            display alert"Button Cancel clicked!"
            end if```

Comment: could you please give me an example?
I would like to remember the user's decision using Suppression Button

Comment: Normally this kind of thing would be saved to the user defaults with a preference setting or some other means to reset it, so I’ve added that to my example.  Note that the user defaults will not be updated if you use Xcode to stop the app.